# Format dates using Windows form in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, ado.net

I am trying to update the database with the following query, but I am having difficulty formatting dates. What should I do?

```
string query = "update employee_info set FirstName ='txtfirstName.Text',LastName ='txtlastName.Text' ,Address1='txt_address', City = 'combo_city' ,Country='combo_Country',ReportsTo='txt_reportTo' WHERE  Bday='dtp_birthDate.Value.ToShortDateString()' and HireDate='dtp_hireDate.Value.ToShortDateString()'";
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **never EVER** concatenate together your SQL statements - ***ALWAYS*** use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: please do not post the question only in question title

Answer (score 0):

You should use a parameterized query instead. This gets you around having to format the strings for the where clause correctly and also prevents you from being vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Something like this (the below sample has a shortened version of your query and lacks setting up a db connection).

```
strQuery = "update employee_info set FirstName=@firstName, LastName=@lastName  WHERE  Bday=@birthDate and HireDate=@hireDate";
cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", txtfirstName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", txtLastName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthDate", dtp_birthDate.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hireDate", dtp_hireDate.Value);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```